# Is CUDA 11.5 compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 + Nvidia 470 driver + Geforce GTX Titan?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, cuda

I can't seem to get CUDA 11.5 to work Ubuntu 20.04 + Nvidia 470 driver + Geforce GTX Titan.  After installing this CUDA version and rebooting, a dual monitor system becomes reduced to a single monitor system with a low resolution of 1920x1080 only. Also, a non-Nvidia driver seems to be installed.

I have checked that such a system can be installed with CUDA 11.4, everything works fine with this CUDA version.

Is CUDA 11.5 compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 + Nvidia 470 driver + Geforce GTX Titan?

Comment: You compute capability of 3.5 might be an issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932864/cuda-compute-capability-requirements    Might need to specify something to use the min instead of the default of 5.2

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks. Noted. Those days where cc 3.5 meant something seems fleeting... :)

Comment: In `terminal` do `nvidia-smi` and look in the top-right corner, and it'll tell you what version of cuda is supported (not if it's installed or not). I suspect that yours will say 11.4. Confirm that "Secure Boot" is disabled in your BIOS. Go to `Software & Updates` Additional Drivers tab, and note which driver is selected there. Change if need be.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. It says 11.4. Hence, that is as far as this GPU can go. Secure Boot is disabled. FYI, when 11.5 was installed, the GPU driver became manually set and could not be changed. I had to use `apt purge` to totally remove CUDA 11.5 and then NIDIA , reboot, and reinstall NVIDIA driver as per your description to recover my display. Also, I write this here to help other users encountering the same issue as I have to recover their display.

Comment: @SunBear Yup. That's the way you do it :-) Write that up as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

**Geforce GTX Titan**

No, CUDA 11.5 is not compatible with your current configuration.

- Removed CUDA 11.5 and Nvidia 470
- Reinstalled Nvidia 470 using `Software & Updates` Additional Drivers tab
- Installed CUDA 11.4